# Angular 2: Best way to declare and initialize variables

Tags: angular, typescript, design-patterns

I am studing Angular Style Guide, but I have a doubt, what's the best way to initialize a variable in component?

For example, I declare a variable like this:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  myModel: MyModel= new MyModel();

  //...
}
```

Or like this:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  myModel = new MyModel();

  //...
}
```

Or this:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  myModel: MyModel;

  constructor() {
    this.myModel = new MyModel();
  }

  //...
}
```

Or another best way?
Here's the [Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) I was reading.

Comment: Personally, I user the first one. The style is clear

Comment: @JoshuaFabillar but in style guide there's nothing explicit. That's why I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

first way is redundant, the `"name" : type = new objectType();`
have already specified the variable type;
second one is good, you specify that there is a PUBLIC variable in the class.
third one is good too, but remember that binds the variable to an instance of the class.

Personally i use always the second one. If you use as TextEditor --> Visual Studio Code, download the plugin `TSlint`, is perfect for helps on syntax!

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the second one is "correct". Since you do not have the type information. So you can assign a totally different type to the variable later on.

For the other two, I think it comes down to personal preference and there is no clear style-guide.

I use the first one when I need the variable default assigned or when I don't allow it to change (You also can add a readonly flag as well then)

The third one for all the rest. So if it does not matter whether it is initialized or there is a possibility that the model reference changes multiple times.

In your example since you set the value in the constructor, I personally would choose the first one.